# How to obtain $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma^2 y + (N-1)\sigma_t^2} y^{\frac{N-1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}} dy$?

Tags: integration, statistics, gamma-function

Let $X_1, X_2 \cdots X_N$ be random variables, which follow a Gaussian distribution.

\begin{equation}
X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}
Let the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ be unknown.
The unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ is
\begin{equation}
U = \frac{1}{N-1}\left((X_1 -\bar{X})^2 \cdots (X_N -\bar{X})^2\right)
\end{equation}

I'd like to calculate the mean value of $\tilde{F}=\frac{1}{U + \sigma_t^2}$ where $\sigma_t^2$ is a known parameter.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E\left[\tilde{F} \right]&= E\left[\frac{1}{U + \sigma_t^2}\right] \\
&=  E\left[\frac{N-1}{\sigma^2 Y +  (N-1)\sigma_t^2}\right] \quad (Y \sim \chi_{N-1}^2) \\
&= (N-1) \int_0^{\infty}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2 y + (N-1)\sigma_t^2}
\frac{y^{\frac{N-1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}}
{2^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{N-1}{2})} dy 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
How can I calculate this value?

Comment: Does it converge? What you obtained is an asymptotic expanion, because you integrated beyond the domain of convergence of your $y$-power series. Your integral should be expressible in terms of an incomplete gamma function, cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E4 (replace $y$ by $2t$)

Comment: this only converges when a=0

Comment: Thanks. I understand the expansion should not be used here since it does not converge. So, alternatively, using the equation 8.6.4, the mean value $E[\tilde{F}]$ is $E[\tilde{F}]=
\frac{N-1}{\sigma^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{N-1}{2} \right)}
\Gamma \left(\frac{N+1}{2} \right)
\Gamma \left(\frac{1-N}{2} , 
\frac{(N-1)\sigma_t^2}{2\sigma^2}
\right)
\left(\frac{(N-1)\sigma_t^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)^{\frac{1-N}{2}}
e^{-\frac{(N-1)\sigma_t^2}{2\sigma^2} }
$ Can I simplify this value?

Comment: @KYKY You can use, for instance, $$
\Gamma \!\left( {\frac{{N + 1}}{2}} \right) = \frac{{N - 1}}{2}\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{N - 1}}{2}} \right).
$$

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't the formula be in a simpler form? Of course $E \left[ \frac{1}{U+\sigma_t^2} \right] \neq  \frac{1}{E[U]+\sigma_t^2} =  \frac{1}{\sigma^2+\sigma_t^2} $, but I expected $E \left[ \frac{1}{U+\sigma_t^2} \right]$ to have a similar form to $ \frac{1}{\sigma^2+\sigma_t^2} $ .

Answer (score 1):

Consider \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \int_0^{\infty}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2 y + (N-1)\sigma_t^2}
\frac{y^{\frac{N-1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}}
{2^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{N-1}{2})} dy 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and put $x = y+\frac{(N-1)\sigma_t^2}{\sigma^2}$.

After simplification we get
$$A = const_1 \int_{const_2}^{\infty}x^{-1}(x-const_3)^{\frac{N-3}2}e^{-\frac{x}2}dx$$

If $\frac{N-3}2 = k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can write binomial theorem for $(x-const_3)^{\frac{N-3}2}$ and put $x = 2 z$ and see that $A$ is a sum of incomplete gamma-functions.

If $\frac{N-3}2 \ne k \in \mathbb{Z}$ it looks like there's not good representation.